# Is there a bash command to do this?

Tags: bash

I want to know if new files/directories have been created in a specific directory `A` since a fixed date time.

Is there a bash command to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No, since creation dates aren't stored on most *nix filesystems. Try `find` with the `-amin`, `-atime`, `-mmin`, or `-mtime` predicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ man find
```

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find

Answer (score 0):

use the `touch` command to create a dummy file. eg `touch .dummy`. then use the `find` command with `-newer` option to check for new files. eg

```
find /path -newer .dummy
```

Comment: And you can specify the time with the 'touch' command: `touch -t 201004041659.32` for 2010-04-04 16:59:32.

Comment: Strictly, this gives you files modified since the reference time of the file - not necessarily those which were created.  That may be a good enough approximation.